# WiFi not working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Lenovo Legion Y520

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, lenovo

I got a Lenovo Legion Y520 and first thing I did was install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I ticked the "install third party software for graphics and wifi hardware" tickbox and installed it. However, in WiFi settings, the message "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" is displayed.

The "Additional Drivers" tab in "Software & Updates" doesn't show anything related to WiFi.

I also ran this command in the Terminal:

```
lspci | grep Network
```

and this was the output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

Should I try installing an older version of Ubuntu?

Thanks in Advance.

**Edit:**

I ran this command:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
```

And this is the output:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:0901]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Your wifi appear to be hard blocked. Check for a physical button on the notebook to unblock it.

Comment: There is no button. It is a problem  with new Lenovo models. A kernel quirk is needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The device is blocked by a platform ideapad driver. Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot.

And also I recommend to remove the Broadcom driver that you installed.

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: THANK YOU! If anyone stumbles upon this problem on Arch Linux, the first command fixes the wifi problem! Thanks!

Comment: Fixed for me too, thank you!

Comment: this did not work on Legion 540

Comment: Works on the 2021 Legion 5 with Realtek Semiconductor Corp Device 8852 on Pop!OS 21.04, thank you so much for the help! I was losing my mind over lwfinger/rtw89 not making properly but this fix was so much easier.

Comment: Didn't work for Y530 Ubuntu 22.04