# WiFi problem on lenovo E520 ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: wireless, 18.04, lenovo

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 on my Lenovo E520 yesterday and I have this issue since i tried to connect to WiFi , WiFi connects and everything is ok
but after some time (sometimes minutes, sometimes seconds) the connection gets lost!
I searched for the problem and understood that when I type `rfkill list all` in my terminal I got this:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

I realized that all of them must be "no" but as you can see "Wireless LAN" is "yes" , I tried to make it "no" by typing this `sudo rfkill unblock all` but it works just for few minutes then turning back to "yes" again!
I don't know what to do

Here is my lspci-output :

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1315]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Wireless script result when i type this :

`wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info`

i got :

```
`--2018-12-19 22:54:28--  https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.112, 192.30.253.113
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.112|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/master/wireless-info [following]
--2018-12-19 22:54:30--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/master/wireless-info
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 151.101.112.133
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.112.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 17452 (17K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘wireless-info’
```

wireless-info       100%[===================>]  17.04K  68.1KB/s    in 0.3s

Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2018-12-19 22:54:32 (68.1 KB/s) - ‘wireless-info’ saved [17452/17452]
`
and :

```
chmod +x wireless-info &&
```

> ./wireless-info
>   [sudo] password for saeed:

Results saved in "/home/saeed/wireless-info.txt".

Results also archived in "/home/saeed/wireless-info.tar.gz", as they exceed the 19.5 kB size limit for ".txt" attachments on the Ubuntu Forums.

and also when i type this : `cat wireless-info.txt`
i got :

```
    ########## wireless info START ##########
```

Report from: 19 Dec 2018 22:59 +0330 +0330

Booted last: 19 Dec 2018 00:00 +0330 +0330

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

release

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

kernel

Linux 4.15.0-42-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

desktop

Ubuntu

lspci

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:21e2]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1315]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 147e:1002 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:03b3 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2516 Pixart Imaging, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

PCMCIA card info

rfkill

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

secure boot

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

lsmod

iwldvm                229376  0
mac80211              778240  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               282624  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              622592  3 iwldvm,iwlwifi,mac80211

interfaces

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

ifconfig

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback  brd 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd 
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 86042sec preferred_lft 86042sec
    inet6 fe80::6cf8:ec8:7457:d74d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp8s0:  mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether  brd

iwconfig

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp8s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

route

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 20100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 100

resolv.conf

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search domain.name

network managers

Installed:

```
NetworkManager
```

Running:

root       793     1  0 22:45 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

NetworkManager info

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       97cce32f-3df9-3970-a98e-435e94206f8b
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/5
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.2/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 20100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             85.15.1.14
IP4.DNS[2]:                             85.15.1.15
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          domain.name
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        expiry = 1545333793
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       domain_name = domain.name
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.2
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 85.15.1.14 85.15.1.15
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::6cf8:ec8:7457:d74d/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::76da:daff:fe76:dae9
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::76da:daff:fe76:dae9, mt = 20100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{4}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   97cce32f-3df9-3970-a98e-435e94206f8b | Wired connection 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp8s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] (Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.15.0-42-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               39.31.5.1 build 35138
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:08:00.0/net/wlp8s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE

NetworkManager.state

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=false
WWANEnabled=true

NetworkManager config

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

NetworkManager profiles

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Saeed]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Saeed | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Saeed
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/iPhone]] (600 root)
[connection] id=iPhone | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address= | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=iPhone
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

Netplan config

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

iw reg get

Region: Asia/Tehran (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

iwlist channels

enp2s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp8s0    13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

iwlist scan

wlp8s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

module infos

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation 
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     5144A889CD9311D5F87BAC3
depends:        mac80211,iwlwifi,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwldvm
vermagic:       4.15.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           force_cam:force continuously aware mode (no power saving at all) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     10B87D6D65DDD085D1326C9
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation 
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-jf-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-34.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-34.ucode
srcversion:     773231C3AA2E3CAB7CBD42B
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       4.15.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-42-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     62FD05DCC5AEEA290640C3D
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:
sig_key:
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

module parameters

[iwldvm]
force_cam: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
d0i3_timeout: 1000
disable_11ac: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

/etc/modules

modprobe options

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

rc.local

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

pm-utils

udev rules

dmesg

[   17.809595] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   18.000321] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 35138 op_mode iwldvm
[   18.027511] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   18.027514] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   18.027515] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   18.027517] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1000 BGN, REV=0x6C
[   18.070909] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   18.369621] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0 wlp8s0: renamed from wlan0
[   30.450705] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   30.698802] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[   30.698897] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   30.739108] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp8s0: link is not ready
[   83.047651] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3 (repeated 2 times)
[   83.151089] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp8s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   83.862520] wlp8s0: authenticate with 
[   83.866873] wlp8s0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[   83.869198] wlp8s0: authenticated
[   83.869447] wlp8s0: waiting for beacon from 
[   83.928167] wlp8s0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[   83.935936] wlp8s0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[   83.948506] wlp8s0: associated
[   84.055005] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp8s0: link becomes ready
[  420.823012] wlp8s0: deauthenticating from  by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  421.313490] wlp8s0: authenticate with 
[  421.317148] wlp8s0: send auth to  (try 1/3)
[  421.318899] wlp8s0: authenticated
[  421.319751] wlp8s0: associate with  (try 1/3)
[  421.324047] wlp8s0: RX AssocResp from  (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[  421.328298] wlp8s0: associated
[  496.549637] wlp8s0: deauthenticating from  by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  507.318336] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[  507.318346] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready

#### wireless info END ############

Comment: Heres a link to a page that addresses this problem [solution to lenovo ubuntu wifi issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049132/959500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time searching and asking finally my problem solved by fixing DNS on my internet. So here is the solution:

First save this codes as .sh file (it's a DNS fixer file) on your desktop (you can name the file whatever you want) :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 
##start Local net Cheking
var1=`ip addr | grep brd | wc -l`
var2=`ip addr | awk {'print $1'} | grep : | wc -l`
if [ "$var1" == "$var2" ];then
echo -e "\033[91m[-]Your Are Offline!!!"
exit 1
else
echo -e "\033[92m[+]Your Local Netowkr Is Ok!."
##start internet Checking
ping -c2 -w2 8.8.8.8 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
if [ "$?" != "0" ];then
    echo -e "\033[91m[-]You Have Internet ERROR! CHECK THAT."
    exit 1
    else
    echo -e "\033[92m[+]Your Internet Is OK!"
    ##Start DNS Checking
    nslookup gnu.org -timeout=1 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null 
    if [ "$?" != "0" ];then
        echo -e "\033[91m[-]You Have Dns ERROR! "
        read -p "I cat To Ok That, Do You Want To Contniue?[Y/n] " yesorno
        if [ "$yesorno" == "Y" ] || [ "$yesorno" == "y" ] || [ "$yesorno" == 
        "" ];then
            echo -e "nameserver 208.67.222.222\nnameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee 
            /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail 1>/dev/null
            sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
            else
            echo "Ok, You Need To Fix it." 
            exit 1
            fi
            else
            echo -e "\033[92m[+]Your DNS Is OK!"
            exit 0
            fi
            ##End Of DNS Checking.
            fi
            ##End of internet checking
            fi
            ##End Of Localnet checking
```

After that open your Terminal follow the codes below step by step:

```
cd Desktop
chmod +x FileName.sh
./FileName
reboot
```

Hope It works for you