# Lenovo Legion Y540 wifi problem

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth

I recently installed dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10
and now I'm facing problems with Wi-Fi. It says Wi-Fi is not enabled.

When I modify the network configuration it says "not managed." Below are the details.

`iwconfig`:

```
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Please go through them and help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WiFi not working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Lenovo Legion Y520](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049129/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-lenovo-legion-y520)

Comment: I tried the solution there but it did't work

Comment: Did output of `rfkill list` change? Please add output of `grep ideapad /etc/modprobe.d/*` to your question.

Comment: Check this answer. This fixed it for me. https://superuser.com/questions/1462334/wifi-not-working-on-lenovo-legion-y540-15irh

Answer (score 6):

This fixed it

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad-laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
exit
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me Lenovo Legion 540