# Wifi adapter doesn't come on after suspend on 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, suspend

I have been searching through the forums for a general solution to this problem for 18.04 (such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564556/cant-connect-to-wifi-after-suspend) one or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049129/wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-lenovo-legion-y520/1049132#1049132) one).

The first example was originally posted for 14.04 and tells me to add a script to the /etc/pm/sleep.d. I tried two different scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
thaw|resume)
sudo nmcli nm sleep false
sudo pkill -f wpa_supplicant
;;
*)
;;
esac
exit $?
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  resume|thaw)
    nmcli r wifi off && nmcli r wifi on ;;
esac
```

but neither of them worked. I'm not proficient enough in Linux to understand exactly what the scripts are doing but I do get that this should run when resuming from suspend (I did make it executable using sudo chmod +x). In fact just running

```
nmcli nm sleep false
```

in a terminal gave me "Error: argument 'nm' not understood"

An answer on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04) says that sleep.d is no longer active as of 16.04 and that the script should be put in /lib/systemd/systemd-sleep.

The second post seems to be specific to Lenovo laptops as it says to run:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

but I have an HP Pavilion with an Intel Corporation Wireless 3160[8086:08b3] rev (83), as per lspci | grep Network, and there is no "blacklist-ideapad.conf" file in /etc/modprobe.d

There is no hard switch on my laptop for the Wifi adapter so I was hoping someone could help me tweak these answers for my situation. How would I add a similar script to the systemd-sleep since its not a folder or script (that I can read anyway)?

**EDIT**
Based on @nobody's solution here is what my iwlwifi.conf file looks like:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

options iwlwifi remove_when_gone=1
```

Perhaps I didn't add the "options iwlwifi..." line properly?

Thanks for the help!
Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

When I'm right the module iwlwifi is for your wlan.

Please create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` with content

```
options iwlwifi remove_when_gone=1
```

> Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible

Since then I had no Problem anymore with connection after wakeup from suspend to ram or suspend to disk.

More Option for the module `modinfo iwlwifi | fgrep parm`

Comment: Thanks for your response @nobody. I don't really understand the part about "removing dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible". I don't even know how I would know if it were inaccessible, let alone where to begin to remove a dev. Also, to create the file would I use `sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

Comment: I read the modinfo iwlwifi and understand the "Remove dev..." comment. However, this did not work for me. I have edited my original answer to include the contents of my iwlwifi.conf file